# how to select / unselect the checkboxes using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, checkbox, jquery-selectors

I have the following html code

### html code

```
<p><a href="" onclick="select()">Select All</a>&nbsp; / &nbsp;<a href="" onclick="unselect()" >Unselect All</a> </p>

{% for field in fields %}
  <div class="contact_align">    
    <input id="select-unselect" type="checkbox" name="invite" value="so">{{ field }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function select(){
                $('#select-unselect').attr('checked',true);
            }
    function unselect(){
                $('#select-unselect').attr('checked',false);
            }               
</script>
```

so above is my code, and the functionality is not working , so can anyone please let me know what i am doing wrong in the above code and make it work ?

Comment: It looks like you are creating the checkboxes in a loop with an ID. That id needs to be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `return false` in your functions. Otherwise the `a` tags are just behaving as normal `a` tags and thus going to the `href` specified.
And change the `attr(...)` for `prop(...)`.

```
function select(){
    $('#select-unselect').prop('checked',true);
    return false;
}

function unselect(){
    $('#select-unselect').prop('checked',false);
    return false;
}
```

Or toggle it in one function like this:

```
function select(){
    $('#select-unselect').prop('checked',function(id,checked){ return !checked; });
    return false;
}
```

But I would recommend changing the id `#select-unselect` to a class `.select-unselect` because you can't have duplicate ids.

Also change `<input id="select-unselect" type="checkbox" name="invite" value="so">{{ field }}` to `<input class="select-unselect" type="checkbox" name="invite" value="so">{{ field }}`

Comment: now its i had changed `href="javascript"`, but  when i clicked on `selectAll` its selecting only one starting checkbox field, not all checkboxes y so ?

Comment: Yes, so you need to change your ids to classes as the second part of my answer says. Because JavaScript / jQuery only can select one ID (the first one).

Comment: k thanks its working after i had changed `id to class`, and anyway whether we can implement this functionality with only one function instead of two functions? i mean by assigning same function to both select and unselect links ?

Answer (score 2):

use .prop(), also since you have multiple elements with the same id use class instead of id

```
<input class="select-unselect" type="checkbox" name="invite" value="so">{{ field }}
```

Then

```
$('.select-unselect').prop('checked',true);
```

Comment: k but now , if i have four checkbox fields and when  clicked on `selectall`, only one checkbox has been selecting and immedialtely disappearing(may be its refereshing)

Answer (score 0):

Use Prop instead of attr. Please see this link [Jquery Attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)  to see the difference between attr and prop.
$('#select-unselect').prop('checked',true);

And try to use class instead of id of a control.